# What is superclass mismatch in Crystal Lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

I am trying to implement a rate-limiting handler with Kemal.

I have a class, `RateLimiter`, that inherits the class `Kemal::Handler`. On compile I get the error:

`Error in src/rate_limiter.cr:5: superclass mismatch for class RateLimiter (Kemal::Handler for Reference)`

I'm new to Crystal and that means nothing to me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This indicates that `RateLimiter` was defined previously somewhere, without any explicit superclass specification:

```
class Base; end
class Foo; end
class Foo < Base; end
```

That gives

```
Error in line 3: superclass mismatch for class Foo (Base for Reference)
```

https://carc.in/#/r/3r2l

Search through your project and dependencies for `class RateLimiter` giving conflicting definitions of that type.

Comment: That was it. I had defined RateLimiter to give it a VERSION constant.